# Fixing Numerical Sort with Table Sorter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting, html-table

I am having a strange issue with a Table Sorter Plugin (http://tablesorter.com/docs/)
The numerical sort seems to not work when sorting with $'s and ,'s. Here is a screenshot of what it is doing. Does anybody know how to fix this?

[image: picture of problem]

Here is my table sorting code on the page with the table

```
$(document).ready(function(load) 
    { 
        $("#myTable").tablesorter({ 
            sortList: [[1,1]] // etc.

    }); 
    } 
);
```

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't detect the type automatically (as it should), you can force it.   Here is an example from the comments in the source code:

```
 $('table').tablesorter({ headers: { 0: {sorter:"integer"}, 1: {sorter:"currency"} } });
```

In this case, it looks like the second column should be sorted as currency.

Comment: It's the 6th column on the table. How would I incorporate it with the current code I have for the js? I tried it and it didn't even sort anything.

Comment: You know the 6th column would be something like: 5:{sorter: "currency"}  Columns are zero based.  I don't know what your current code is so I can't help you integrate anything.

Comment: Right, it's the 7th column but  saying 6 because of the zero basing. The current code is below the screenshot on the first post.

Comment: You can see that it is already sorting, but it's not sorting correctly.

Comment: I can't see anything.  You didn't post any HTML.

Answer (score 0):

my experienced eyes saw that your list is mis-sorted if there is a comma "," as decimal character separator but the js expect it to have locale that uses "." as separator

you could easily replace the commas with dots just google for "jquery replace"
but i would rather introduce you n numeral.js, wich has handy functions http://numeraljs.com/
or even better would be to output the correct data format from serverside

btw with numeral you could simply do

```
number = numeral(number).format('$0.0.00');
```